# Add new sealers in aura network without hard-fork?

Tags: parity, nodes, proof-of-authority, poa

I've set up a private PoA (aura) network using [parity-deploy](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-deploy) and was wondering how it's possible to add/remove authorised nodes without doing a hard-fork of the network.

I've heard about people storing them in a smart contract, however I have not found any documentation on how to do this. Any pointer in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now detailed documentation available on the [official docs](https://wiki.parity.io/Validator-Set.html).[parity-deploy](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-deploy) with the aura parameter seems to deploy a Validator Set contract.

The details on how to add/remove validators with Validator Set contracts are given [here](https://wiki.parity.io/Validator-contracts.html). Essentially, each node has a set of validators which it supports. Validators are part of the network as long as at least half of all nodes support them.

By using the function `addValidator` of the RelaySet contract (part of the Validator Set contracts), you can add a validator, as shown in detail [here](https://wiki.parity.io/Validator-Set-Tutorial-3.html).
You can remove support and report misbehaviors. An example for this is given [here](https://wiki.parity.io/Validator-Set-Tutorial-4.html#title-visualize-misbehaviors). Essentially, a Dapp monitors other nodes and if they are down, sends a transaction to the `reportBenign` function of the RelaySet contract. This function must be called twice to fully remove support - this way a node may change its mind after the first report by calling `absolveFirstBenign`.

Initially you need to find the address of the contract to conduct any transactions. According to [parity-deploy documentation](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-deploy), you should be able to find the relevant addresses in the deployment folder's `authority.toml`.

Comment: Happy to accept your answer if you summarise what's in the docs (for the sake of other people searching this).

Comment: I have updated the reply to include detailed info on the necessary ABI calls